# How to add Group in Openfire using XMPP programmatically

Tags: xmpp, openfire, members

I want to create GROUP in openfire using xmpp programmatically
see the image....
[image]

there are two groups in image I wish to add new groups in openfire using xmpp stanzas. If success then I wish to add members in particular groups.

I know how to create chat rooms (MUC) but groups are different than chatrooms. in groups rosters are persistent but in chatroom any user can enter and can at leave any time. so I want to create groups not like chatrooms.

I tried lot but it creates chatrooms only not the groups.

Answer (score 1):

See this [post](http://www.massapi.com/source/openfire_src/src/java/org/jivesoftware/openfire/commands/admin/group/AddGroup.java.html) for instance, if it can help you a little bit. Look for the [addgroup](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/commands/admin/group/AddGroup.html) in the java docs on the openfire.